# pass EJB ApplicationException to web

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I have EJB class, custom exception and web back end bean classes, i want to catch the custom exception in the web if the EJB pass the exception, but the `RuntimeException` catch the exception??

***Exception Class:***

```
@ApplicationException
public class CustomException extends Exception { }
```

***EJB Class:***

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    private UserTransaction transaction;
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="xxx")
    protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    . . . . .

    public void addNewEmployee(Employee employee) throws CustomException {
        . . . .
        throw new CustomException (...);
    }
}
```

***Backend Class:***

```
public class EmployeeBackend {
    . . . .

    public void doAddEmployee() {
        try {
            ....
            employeeDao.addNewEmployee();
        } catch(CustomException  e) {
            System.err.println("------------------------ CustomException"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(RuntimeException  e) {
            System.err.println("------------------------ RuntimeException  "); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is after i cover the main Exception with the custom Exception, there are system exception happen, so the custom Exception doesn't pass, only the system exception is pass :)